# Using jQuery or javascript, I'd like to get that how many element 500 in each column (1-4) of an html table is ? How should I do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery or javascript, I'd like to get that how many element 500 in each column (1-4) of an html table is ? How should I do it ?

```html
<html>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column-1</th>
      <th>Column-2</th>
      <th>Column-3</th>
      <th>Column-4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>501</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

The table is look like this format:

```
 Column-1 Column-2 Column-3  Column-4
 500        200     500       200
 501        500     500       500
 ...        ...     ....      ...
```

I would like to get : column-1: 1, column-2:1, column-3:2 column-4: 1

automatic display the numbers of "500" of each column .

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is for help with existing code, not to ask for us to write it from scratch for you. You know you'll need to use JS/jQuery, so start there. Try selecting any column to start. Then try getting some data from a column or cell? Maybe you can iterate over the data in a column and save it in a variable? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information and tips on asking a good question.

Comment: You have nested TRs now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

- filter the 's in row out
- Store the column when the text of a td is 500
- Count how often the column occurs

```js
let trArr = $("table tr")
    let res = [];
for (let i = 0; i < trArr.length; i++) {
    let childs = trArr[i].children;
    for (let j = 0; j < childs.length; j++) {
        if(childs[j].tagName !== "TH"){
            if (childs[j].textContent === "500" ) {
                
                      res.push({
                        "column": j+1 
                      });

            }


    }
  }

}
    let result = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    let counter = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
    if (res[i].column === res[j].column) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  result.add(`Column ${[res[i].column]}: ${counter} x 500`);
}

let resString = "";
for(let i of result){

    resString += i + "\n";


}
document.getElementById("BLA").innerHTML = resString;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column-1</th>
      <th>Column-2</th>
      <th>Column-3</th>
      <th>Column-4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>501</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p id="BLA"></p>

</html>
```

Comment: Do I need add table id to make it work ?
<script>
    function myFunction() { 
    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");

Comment: No I don't think so in the solution above I also have no table id setted

Comment: dear Alex: Thanks for the help ,  I used your code by add a onclick 
    <script> <script type="text/javascript"> 

    function myTierNoFunction() {

      let trArr = $("#table01 tr")
      let column;.......your code.....

     and output to html  <p id=Result> </p>
     with,  document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML =  i 
     </script> 
     but only last row and column-3 is displayed. Column-3 : 1 x 500, why ? Do I need 
    use another table for each cell display ?

Comment: can you share your code in a fiddle? Hard to say so @Jason

Comment: my code is a dynamic table retrieve mongodb users collection,  so I have to make it simple in fiddle as static a table with hard coded numbers.  Thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jasonliang2021/ymasvqu1/40/#&togetherjs=eNpwfRQodd

Comment: @Jason the problem is at the moment it just works with fixed rows as you can see in the first loop I "filter" the th columns out whilst start counting at i = 3; so you have to filter the <th> rows out. 
I will look for a solution and ipdate it here

Comment: I have updated my solution you have to filter out the th headings         `if(childs[j].tagName !== "TH"){`

Comment: MY problem is  the document.getElementById("Tier").innerHTML =  i  can not be same as console.log(i) to display i  append , line by line. but display the last round result.

Comment: You can insert the result string in your <p> what do you mean by last round result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227458/discussion-between-alex-and-jason).

Comment: It works great,  I forgot "#" for id in let trArr = $("#table01 tr").  Thanks Alex.

Comment: @Jason you're welcome :) If you think this was helpful mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thank you very much , both of your  algorithm solutions working well in my application. 500 501 ... are  members id, columns represent tiers, in my system. I just try to find this guy own how many tiers, in which tier and times.  Find his tree position. Tier1, Tier2, Tier3 ?  matrix tree.  tier 1, tier 2: 4, Tier 3: 16, Tier 4: 64. members , and your  algorithm works great,  Thank you again.

Comment: Glad that it helped you :)